# Can I use a single token generation mechanism for all my PHP token needs?

Tags: php, token

For example, right now I only need to generate tokens for persistent "remember me" logins. To generate those tokens I am using:

`sha1(uniqid(mt_rand(), true))`

which always generates 40 characters in [0-9a-f] like so:

`64070e8f3d155550b04272eae330d23896e043e6`

Can I generate tokens in the same way for password reset functionality and email account verification? In general, is there one token generation mechanism I can use for all my token needs? Or is it likely that I'll have to use different types of tokens for different needs?

Comment: Since we don't know what your **needs** are - then yes, you can use the same token mechanism for whatever purpose you require somewhat unique 40 character string. However, why use `SHA1` if you have `uniqid` already is beyond me, I'd just stick with `uniqid`.

Comment: Right now my needs are: token is cookie value for persistent logins; token is in password reset URL user clicks on in email; token is in email verification URL users clicks on in email. I use that combination of functions because..when i was researching the best token to use for persistent logins that's what i came up with from SO. how do i determine if the token needs to be unique vs somewhat unique?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can use the same token generator for different purposes. As long as it suits them, you don't have to mess with different mechanisms, keep it simple

Comment: how do i know if it doesn't suit them?

Comment: I mean if it suits your requirements